# Script loading data file from command prompt

Tags: python, csv, sys

Kinda new to this, and writing a script that loads in latitudes and longitudes from a CSV file and converts the formatting for another program to read...finally got it all to work.

I was wondering how I might set this up so I could maybe run ./converter.py filename.csv from a command prompt rather then having the filename embedded in the script?

Currently I have this:

```
csv_file = open('Vicksburg_9mph_dm.csv') #Defines name of file to open
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',') #Opens file as CSV File
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you have a working program (albeit hardcoded for filenames), I'll provide a solution:

```
import sys
import csv

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r', newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    # do your work you already do
```

A couple notes:

`sys` module contains access to pass CLI arguments

`sys.argv` is a list of argument variables as discussed in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

`with open()` syntax is referred to as a *context manager*. In your provided code, you technically never called `close()` so the file remained open. When you exit the `with` block, the file with automatically close.

`newline=''` flag is specific to Python 3, if you do not have that version simply omit it